# First element of series to cross threshold in numpy, with handling of series that never cross

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of N time series of length T. I want the index at which each first crosses some threshold, and a -1 or something similar if it never crosses.  Take `ts_array = np.randn(N, T)`

`np.argmax(ts_array > cutoff, axis=1)` gets close, but it returns a 0 for both time series that cross the threshold at time 0, and time series that never cross.

`np.where(...)` and `np.nonzero(...)` are possibilities, but their return values would require rather gruesome handling to extract the vector in which I'm interested

This question is similar to [Numpy first occurence of value greater than existing value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243955/numpy-first-occurence-of-value-greater-than-existing-value) but none of the answers there solve it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One liner:

```
(ts > c).argmax() if (ts > c).any() else -1
```

assuming `ts = ts_array` and `c = cutoff`

Otherwise:

Use `argmax()` and `any()`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])

def xover(ts, cut):
    x = ts > cut
    return x.argmax() if x.any() else -1

ts_array = np.random.random(5).round(4)
```

`ts_array` looks like:

```
print ts_array, '\n'

[ 0.4449  0.4076  0.4601  0.4652  0.4627]
```

Various checks:

```
print xover(ts_array, 0.400), '\n'

0 

print xover(ts_array, 0.460), '\n'

2 

print xover(ts_array, 0.465), '\n'

3 

print xover(ts_array, 1.000), '\n'

-1
```

Comment: Thanks, but (as mentioned in my comment to SNygard) ts_array is a 2D structure so I'd need to map this to each row. That's doable, I'd just rather have a nice vectorized one-liner, but that may just not exist.

Comment: @MHankin This is a vectorized solution.  It could also be a one-liner.  One-liner solutions are often harder to read and less efficient.  For example, with my solution, I could have written `(ts > c).argmax() if (ts > c).any() else -1` given `ts = ts_array` and `c = cutoff`.  `(ts > c).argmax()` is vectorized as is `(ts > c).any()`.  I gain advantage by assigning `x = ts > c` so I don't have to calculate twice.  I'll update the answer with the one-liner equivalent, but it is less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

It's not too bad with `np.where`. I would use the following as a starting point:

```
ts_array = np.random.rand(10, 10)
cutoff = 0.5

# Get a list of all indices that satisfy the condition
rows, cols = np.where(ts_array > cutoff)
if len(rows) > 0:
    index = (rows[0], cols[0])
else:
    index = -1
```

Note that `np.where` returns two arrays, a list of row indices and a list of column indices. They are matched, so choosing the first one of each array will give us the first instance where the values are above the cutoff. I don't have a nice one-liner, but the handling code isn't too bad. It should be easily adaptable to your situation.

Comment: Thanks, but ts_array is a 2D structure (see the example initialization I added to my question) so I'd need to map this to each row, which just compounds the ugliness, as `where(...)` on a 2D boolean array returns 2 1D vectors specifying the row and column indices. Parsing that would be gruesome.

Comment: I changed my code to reflect the 2D `np.where` solution. If you want a list of indices that pass the threshold, you can use `list(zip(np.where(ts_array > cutoff)))`. How are you selecting which is the *first* instance?