# Find the nth time a specific value is exceeded in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This is an extension of the question asked here:
[Numpy first occurrence of value greater than existing value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243955/numpy-first-occurence-of-value-greater-than-existing-value)

```
N = 10000
aa = np.arange(-N,N)
```

In this numpy array, I want to find the index where the array exceeds 0 for the 10th time. To find where it exceeds 0 for the first time, I can simply do:

```
np.argmax(aa>0.0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work from the same principles as the "first time" case, just with a slightly more complicated middle step.

Start with the boolean array representing your condition:

```
cond = aa > 0
```

Convert the True/False values in the array to counts:

```
counts = np.cumsum(cond)
```

Search for the first occurrence of the count you're looking for:

```
idx = np.searchsorted(counts, 10)
```

Remember that the `10` in this last line refers to the tenth value that satisfies the condition, and the first value has count `1`.

---

Alternately, you could convert the condition array to indices:

```
indices, = np.nonzero(cond)
idx = indices[9]
```

Note that in this setup, the tenth value will be at index `9`.