# First occurrence in numpy logics

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have a `numpy.ndarray`:

```
a = np.array([0,4,10,0,11,10])
```

I compared this with 10.

```
a >= 10
# array([False, False,  True, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

I would like to have **a single True**, i.e. True only at the **first occurrence.**

I would like to apply this to a **given axis in n-D numpy.ndarray.(say, 1000*1000*10)**

```
a_2d = np.array([[0,4,10],[0,11,10]])
#if axis == 1: array([[False, False, True], [False, True, False]])
```

**What I have done:**

As for a 1-D array, I managed to do it by using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243955/numpy-first-occurence-of-value-greater-than-existing-value).

```
b=np.zeros(a.size)
b[np.argmax(a>=10)]=True
#b=array([ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

However, I have no idea how to apply this to a large **n-D array**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work with no `for` loops, for 1D or 2D:

```
def firstByRow(a, f = lambda x: x >= 10):
    b = (np.cumsum(f(a), axis = -1) == 1).T
    b[1:] = b[1:] * np.equal(b[1:], np.diff((f(a)).astype(int), axis = -1).T)
    return b.T
```

Not sure if it would be faster than a slightly loopier code though, as it does both `cumsum` and `diff`

**EDIT:**

You can also do this, which is probably faster (leveraging that `np.unique(return_index = True)` picks the first occurrence):

```
def firstByAxis(a, f = lambda x: x >= 10, axis = 0):
    c = np.where(f(a))
    i = np.unique(c[axis], return_index = True)[1]
    b = np.zeros_like(a)
    b[tuple(np.take(c, i, axis = -1))] = 1
    return b
```

Comment: The second seems fantastic. Just that I think you forgot to define `b = np.zeros(a.shape)` Is there any way to add axis to this method? I believe its something to do with np.unique but I cannot manage it.

Comment: I did forget the zeros, sorry.  You can change `r` to `c` as the argument of `np.unique` to do the same thing column-wise

Comment: Added an axis to the function

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a_2d = np.array([[0,4,10],[0,11,10]])
>>> r, c = np.where( a_2d >= 10 )
>>> mask = r+c == (r+c).min()
>>> highMask = np.zeros(np.shape(a_2d))
>>> highMask[r[mask], c[mask]] = 1
>>> highMask
    array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.],
           [ 0.,  1.,  0.]])
```

There is no such thing as the 'first' one in a 2D array. In a 2D array, the minimum indices will form a line on the 2D axis, the both of which will have minimum indices values. For a 3D matrix, this will be a surface, etc ..

Example of such a line would be:

```
 0 0 0 0 0 1
 0 0 0 0 1 0
 0 0 0 1 0 0
 0 0 1 0 0 0
 0 1 0 0 0 0
 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

All of which are equidistant from the [0,0] location ...

Answer (score 0):

If you `enumerate` over the argmax, you can update your `zeros` array.

**Code:**

```
a = np.array([[0, 4, 10], [0, 11, 10]])
print(a)

b = np.zeros(a.shape)
for i, j in enumerate(np.argmax(a >= 10, axis=1)):
    b[i, j] = 1
print(b)
```

**Results:**

```
[[ 0  4 10]
 [ 0 11 10]]

[[ 0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]]
```

**Using advanced indexing:**

```
c = np.zeros(a.shape)
c[list(range(a.shape[0])), np.argmax(a >= 10, axis=1)] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I would like to avoid using "for loops" (because that's the main reason I use Numpy)

Comment: This is only a loop per column.  The speed up is in the argmax.

Comment: I should have added that the number of columns is also rather big.