# Numpy: Fastest way to insert value into array such that array's in order

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, concatenation

Suppose I have an array `my_array` and a singular value `my_val`. (Note that `my_array` is always sorted).

```
my_array = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
my_val = 1.5
```

Because `my_val` is 1.5, I want to put it in between 1 and 2, giving me the array `[1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

My question is: What's the fastest way (i.e. in microseconds) of producing the ordered output array as `my_array` grows arbitrarily large?

The original way I though of was concatenating the value to the original array and then sorting:

```
arr_out = np.sort(np.concatenate((my_array, np.array([my_val]))))
[ 1.   1.5  2.   3.   4.   5. ]
```

I know that `np.concatenate` is fast but I'm unsure how `np.sort` would scale as `my_array` grows, even given that `my_array` will always be sorted.

Edit:

I've compiled the times for the various methods listed at the time an answer was accepted:

Input:

```
import timeit

timeit_setup = 'import numpy as np\n' \
               'my_array = np.array([i for i in range(1000)], dtype=np.float64)\n' \
               'my_val = 1.5'
num_trials = 1000

my_time = timeit.timeit(
    'np.sort(np.concatenate((my_array, np.array([my_val]))))',
    setup=timeit_setup, number=num_trials
)

pauls_time = timeit.timeit(
    'idx = my_array.searchsorted(my_val)\n'
    'np.concatenate((my_array[:idx], [my_val], my_array[idx:]))',
    setup=timeit_setup, number=num_trials
)

sanchit_time = timeit.timeit(
    'np.insert(my_array, my_array.searchsorted(my_val), my_val)',
    setup=timeit_setup, number=num_trials
)

print('Times for 1000 repetitions for array of length 1000:')
print("My method took {}s".format(my_time))
print("Paul Panzer's method took {}s".format(pauls_time))
print("Sanchit Anand's method took {}s".format(sanchit_time))
```

Output:

```
Times for 1000 repetitions for array of length 1000:
My method took 0.017865657746239747s
Paul Panzer's method took 0.005813951002013821s
Sanchit Anand's method took 0.014003945532323987s
```

And the same for 100 repetitions for an array of length 1,000,000:

```
Times for 100 repetitions for array of length 1000000:
My method took 3.1770704101754195s
Paul Panzer's method took 0.3931240139911161s
Sanchit Anand's method took 0.40981490723551417s
```

Comment: You can simply run an experiment to see how each method scales as the list grows larger. Are you expecting someone else to do it for you?

Comment: @YilunZhang I'm more so wondering what other methods may exist that I haven't thought of.

Comment: I think the most usual ways are: 1) append + sort, and 2) insert directly to the correct index location.

Comment: @YilunZhang so how would you identify the correct index and perform the insert? That's clearly the approach the OP is looking for and they have shown effort on this problem.

Comment: Actually the speed of finding the index will not matter that much, since inserting in a numpy array takes linear time, any boost of searching the index, will be neglegible, we would only win up to 50%, but it will still be (very) slow for large arrays.

Comment: It might better to work with a list, maybe even a heap.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem With up to 50%, I guess you're thinking of a linear search for the index instead of binary search? In that case I suspect you'd save significantly *more* than 50% by switching to binary search. (I don't know much NumPy though, and how to do such a linear search.)

Comment: @StefanPochmann: no, what I mean is that if we do linear search, then we have two *O(n)* algorithms, that will approximately run in the same time, if we manage to completely remove the search part, then the remaining insertion algorithm will still approximately take 50% of the time, in fact it will usually take more time, so even if we could find a way (impossible without proper structures) to detect the insertion point in constant time (and in zero nanoseconds), then that would not make the insertion algorithm any faster, hence the total would not have a dramatic speedup.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That's what I meant. But I think the linear insertion time might take *less* time than the linear search time, not more. So that somehow getting rid of that search time would improve by *more* than 50%. What's a fast linear time index search? (Like I said I'm not good enough at NumPy for this)

Comment: @StefanPochmann: well insertion means that - given we do it inplace - we have to move objects to the right by one hop (at the right of the insertion point). This means that we need to perform a fetch, and a write. Whereas linear search only need to do a *read*. Usually memory (if not in cache) is very slow compared to the CPU, so my guess is that insertion is typically slower.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Hmm, apparently there even isn't a way to do it inplace? At least `np.insert` doesn't work inplace and I couldn't find a way that is. In a little test, my linear search was indeed faster than `np.insert` but significantly *slower* than shifting by slice assignment (to simulate what inplace insertion would be like): https://ideone.com/GBmHx9

Comment: `insert` creates a new array. either with concatenate, or creating a blank and copying values.  You can't grow an ndarray in-place.  Its size is fixed.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: and I think the reason that your search takes almost twice the time, is because the `a >= x` first evaluates *all* elements, whereas a linear search typically cuts of search from the moment it finds the match. If we work with `argmax(a[:x+1] >= x)` we get a faster timing.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Not almost twice the time but over 2.7 times as much. And again, I'm not good at NumPy, I just took that one from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16244044/1672429). If you have a faster linear search, please share :-)

Comment: @StefanPochmann: well since we know that `x` is in the left part of the list we can "mimic" the cutoff with https://ideone.com/aL97Zr.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yeah but you can't assume to know that. In general you don't. If you already knew where it is, you wouldn't search. So what's a fast general one? Also, you use `a[:x//2+1]` but should use `a[:x+1]`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: yeah you are correct that it should be `x+1`, but the idea is here of course to mimic a more smart way to do it. But I do not think that numpy is actually tailored towards such operations. The idea of numpy is to use it when you want to process things in *batch* (like multiplying huge matrices), so inserting a single element in an array, is actually not a good fit for numpy at all.

Comment: Note that the sort type matters here. If you know that the array is mostly sorted, then you should use a sort algorithm that leverages this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `np.searchsorted` to find the insertion point in logarithmic time:

```
>>> idx = my_array.searchsorted(my_val)
>>> np.concatenate((my_array[:idx], [my_val], my_array[idx:]))
array([1. , 1.5, 2. , 3. , 4. , 5. ])
```

Note 1: I recommend looking at @Willem Van Onselm's and @hpaulj's insightful comments.

Note 2: Using `np.insert` as suggested by @Sanchit Anand may be slightly more convenient if all datatypes are matching from the beginning. It is, however, worth mentioning that this convenience comes at the cost of significant overhead:

```
>>> def f_pp(my_array, my_val):
...      idx = my_array.searchsorted(my_val)
...      return np.concatenate((my_array[:idx], [my_val], my_array[idx:]))
... 
>>> def f_sa(my_array, my_val):
...      return np.insert(my_array, my_array.searchsorted(my_val), my_val)
...
>>> my_farray = my_array.astype(float)
>>> from timeit import repeat
>>> kwds = dict(globals=globals(), number=100000)
>>> repeat('f_sa(my_farray, my_val)', **kwds)
[1.2453778409981169, 1.2268288589984877, 1.2298014000116382]
>>> repeat('f_pp(my_array, my_val)', **kwds)
[0.2728819379990455, 0.2697303680033656, 0.2688361559994519]
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
my_array = np.insert(my_array,my_array.searchsorted(my_val),my_val)
```

[EDIT] make sure that the array is of type float32 or float64, or add a decimal point to any of the list elements while initializing it.

Comment: Did you actually bother looking at the result of your suggestion?

Comment: Note that this makes everything a `numpy.int32` by default

Comment: What is wrong with it? It works fine on my PC. You have to declare your array as type float64 or float32 (or just add a decimal point somewhere while initializing).

Comment: @SanchitAnand _You have to declare your array as type float64._ Don't you think that's something worth mentioning in your answer?