# Numpy: how do I get the smallest index for which a property is true

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array that is one dimensional. I would like to get the biggest and the smallest index for which a property is true.

For instance,

```
A = np.array([0, 3, 2, 4, 3, 6, 1, 0])
```

and I would like to know the smallest index for which the value of `A` is larger or equal to `4`.

I can do

```
i = 0
while A[i] < 4:
    i += 1
print("smallest index", i)

i = -1
while A[i] <4:
    i -= 1
print("largest index", len(A)+i)
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

---

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16244044/3128109),

```
np.argmax(A>=4)
```

returns `3`, which is indeed the smallest index. But this doesn't give me the largest index.

Comment: Do you need the biggest and smallest occurrences?

Comment: Sorry, I meant index not occurrence. So the answer linked doesn't answer your question?

Comment: From the link, I'm still missing how to get the largest index.

Comment: To get the maximum value, you can use `np.argmax(A == A[A >= 4].max())`. This however, will only return the first index with this value. So it will ignore duplicate values of the max value. This returns `5`. Tried to answer, but the ability has been removed, since it's marked as a duplicate

Comment: @Josmoor98 If the last element of `A` is `4` rather than `1`, np.argmax(A == A[A >= 4].max()) returns `5` instead of `7`. This doesn't work

Comment: I see what you mean now. You can use `np.where(A>=4)` to return all index values meeting your condition. Then just select the first and last occurrence to get the min/max values. So `np.where(A>=4)` returns `array([3, 5, 7])`, then you can just slice the first and last values, or use `.min()` and `.max()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like. As per the comments, if `A` is.

```
A = np.array([0, 3, 2, 4, 3, 6, 1, 4])

idx_values = np.where(A >= 4)[0]
min_idx, max_idx = idx_values[[0, -1]]

print(idx_values)
# array([3, 5, 7], dtype=int64)
```

`idx_values` returns all the index values meeting your condition. You can then access the smallest and largest index positions.

```
print(min_idx, max_idx)
# (3, 7)
```