# Replacing in place for ordered list python

Tags: python

```
feature_min = 0
feature_max = 100
feature_range = np.linspace(feature_min, feature_max, num = 10)
rng = np.random.uniform(0, 100)
```

I have the above code and I generate a random number between 0-100. Whatever the random number is I want to put it within the sorted `feature_range` list by replacing it an element in the list depending on where it needs to be. The max and the min should never be replaced.

For example if my list is

```
[0,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
```

and `rng = 14` I would replace 20 with 14 to get

```
[0,14,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
```

how can I do this?

Comment: There will always be two valid options you can replace. Which one would you like to use?

Comment: for numpy array see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243955/numpy-first-occurrence-of-value-greater-than-existing-value

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Any of them would be valid

Answer (score 1):

For python list use bisect for greater efficiency

```
import bisect
a = [0, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
x = 14
i = bisect.bisect(a, x, lo=1, hi=len(a) - 1)
if 0 < i < len(a) - 1:
    a[i] = x
print(i, a)
```

With numpy use `searchsorted`, which is numpy's reimplementation of bisect    https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html

Comment: What are `a`, `x` and `n`?

Comment: what if there are multiple 20s in list?

Comment: if there are several 20 then only the first 20 is replaced, which is what requested wanted I believe