# Replace first occurence of 0 in a 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D array:

```
[[1,2,0,0],
[4,0,9,4],
[0,0,1,0],
[4,6,9,0]]
```

is there an efficient way (without using loops) to replace every first 0 in the array, with a 1:

```
[[1,2,1,0],
[4,1,9,4],
[1,0,1,0],
[4,6,9,1]]
```

?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Are you working with a `numpy.ndarray`, or a *list* which is what you have posted above?

Comment: Hi, what is it that you tried for this as code? e.g., can you detect 0s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a one-liner inspired by the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243955/numpy-first-occurrence-of-value-greater-than-existing-value):

```py
a = np.array([
    [1, 2, 0, 0],
    [4, 0, 9, 4],
    [0, 0, 1, 0],
    [4, 6, 9, 0]
])
a[range(len(a)), np.argmax(a == 0, axis=1)] = 1
```

Comment: Risks changing a nonzero entry in the array in case no 0 exists in a row.

Answer (score 1):

So, you can use `np.where` to get the indices of the rows and columns where the array is 0:

```
In [45]: arr = np.array(
    ...:    [[1,2,0,0],
    ...:     [4,0,9,4],
    ...:     [0,0,1,0],
    ...:     [4,6,9,0]]
    ...: )

In [46]: r, c = np.where(arr == 0)
```

Then, use `np.unique` to get the unique x values, which will correspond to the *first* incidence of `0` in each row, and use `return_index` to get the indices to extract the corresponding column values:

```
In [47]: uniq_val, uniq_idx = np.unique(r, return_index=True)

In [48]: arr[uniq_val, c[uniq_idx]] = 1

In [49]: arr
Out[49]:
array([[1, 2, 1, 0],
       [4, 1, 9, 4],
       [1, 0, 1, 0],
       [4, 6, 9, 1]])
```

If performance is really an issue, you could just write a `numba` function, I suspect this would be very amenable to `numba`