# How to read excel file until a unique merged row in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a excel file like this:

|Time   |Position   |Symbol |Type   |Volume |Price|
|-------|-----------|-------|-------|-------|-----|
|2022.04.01 15:39:38    |1111   |US500  |sell   |1  |4 |552.40|
|2022.04.01 16:34:36    |22222  |US500  |sell   |0.5    |4 |543.20|
**orders**

The "orders" is a merged column spanning columns from Time to Price.

At the moment I'm selecting what I want by:

```
df = df.iloc[:446,:]
```

but it is not dynamic, and the length of the table file varies every time.

How can I select the table from the beginning until (and excluded) the row with the string "orders"?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why the table is not formatted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to calculate your magic number 446 dynamically. There are many ways of achieving this. I would start with the solution to this question here:

[Numpy first occurrence of value greater than existing value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243955/numpy-first-occurrence-of-value-greater-than-existing-value)

Solution would be like

```py
stop_at = np.argmax(df["orders_containing_columnname"]=="orders")
df = df.iloc[:stop_at,:]
```

Comment: thanks that works, if "orders" is under a specific column name, but in my case "orders" is written in a merged multi column row, so I don't have a specific column name I guess

Comment: @Steven In a pandas DataFrame each row must have the same number of columns, so it should be a regular column. You might find the right name by `print(df.columns)`. Alternatively use iloc to get the correct columns series if you know the id. (Might be 6 from the table in your question `df.iloc[:,6]`)