# Pandas - Replace Last Non-None Value with None Row-wise

Tags: python, pandas

One common thing people seem to want to do in `pandas` is to replace `None`-values with the next or previous `None`-value. This is easily done with `.fillna`. I however want to do something similar but different.

I have a dataframe, `df`, with some entries. Every row has a different number of entries and they are all "left-adjusted" (if the `df` is 10 columns wide and some row has `n<10` entries the first `n` columns hold the entries and the remaining columns are `None`s).

What I want to do is find the last non-`None` entry in every row and change it to also be a `None`. This could be any of the columns from the first to the last.

I could of course do this with a `for-loop` but my `df`s can be quite large so something quicker would be preferable. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Add reproducible code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from numpy, this is quite easy. By counting the number of `None` in each row one can find for each row the column with the last non-None value. Then using Numpy change this value to `None`:

```
data = np.random.random((6,10))

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.iloc[0, 7:] = None
df.iloc[1, 6:] = None
df.iloc[2, 5:] = None
df.iloc[3, 8:] = None
df.iloc[4, 5:] = None
df.iloc[5, 4:] = None
```

Original dataframe looks like this:

```
          0         1         2         3         4   5
0  0.992337  0.651785  0.521422       NaN       NaN NaN
1  0.912962  0.292458  0.620195  0.507071  0.010205 NaN
2  0.061320  0.565979  0.344755       NaN       NaN NaN
3  0.521936  0.057917  0.359699  0.484009       NaN NaN
```

```
isnull = df.isnull()

col = data.shape[1] - isnull.sum(axis = 1) - 1

df.values[range(len(df)), col] = None
```

Updated dataframe looks like this:

```
          0         1         2         3   4   5
0  0.992337  0.651785       NaN       NaN NaN NaN
1  0.912962  0.292458  0.620195  0.507071 NaN NaN
2  0.061320  0.565979       NaN       NaN NaN NaN
3  0.521936  0.057917  0.359699       NaN NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the index of the element to replace in each row with [`np.argmax()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16244044/14627505):

```py
indices = np.isnan(df.to_numpy()).argmax(axis=1) - 1

df.to_numpy()[range(len(df)), indices] = None
```