# How can I get the row of the first True find in a numpy matrix?

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have the following matrix defined:

```
d = np.array(
      [[False, False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True]])
```

And I would like to get a vector of length 6 containing the index of the first True occurrence in each column.

So the expected output would be:

```
fo = np.array([10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 0])
```

If there would be no `True` values in a given column ideally it shall return `NaN` for that column.

I have tried:

```
np.sum(d, axis=0) 
array([ 4,  8, 12, 16, 20, 23])
```

which together with the length of the columns would give the index, but that would work only if there would be only two continuous regions, one with `False` and another one with `True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [`argmax` which find the first true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16244044/13394817), and then find columns which all is False to cure the result as needed for columns contain only False. e.g. if the first column all is False:

```
# if first column be all False, so it show 0, too; which need additional work using mask
ini = np.argmax(d == 1, 0)  # [0    8    6    4    2    0]   # if we want to fill with nans so convert it to object using ".astype(object)"
sec = (d == 0).all(0)       # find column with all False
ini[sec] = 1000
# [1000    8    6    4    2    0]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, we can iterate through the Numpy array. Then, we can check if True is in the nested array we are looking at. If so, we use `.index()` to find what the index is.

```python
index_list = []
for nested_list in d:
    if True in nested_list:
        index_list.append(nested_list.index(True))
```